# What is this normalization curve? Constant ^ (Constant ^ Observation Indexed to 100)

Tags: statistics, normalization

My apologies, but I'm not quite sure how to even ask this question. I have some normalization curves I've been using at work, and I'd like to know more about them so I speak about them intelligently. They have an s shape like a sigmoid function, but their general formula is the following:

Constant ^ (Constant ^ Observation Indexed to 100)

First, index a variable from 0 to 100 with the highest observation equal to 100, then insert into the equations below for curves with different slopes.

s1 = 0.0000000001 ^ (0.97 ^ Index)

s2 = 0.0000000002 ^ (0.962 ^ Index)

s3 = 0.0000000003 ^ (0.953 ^ Index)

And so on, up to s10. The resulting values are compressed between 0 and 1. s10 has the steepest slope with values that skew toward 1, and s1 has the shallowest slope with values that skew toward 0.

I think they're very clever, and they work well for our purposes, but I don't know what to even call them. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Again, apologies for the vagueness and if this is inappropriately tagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions you describe are special cases of the [Gompertz functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_function); Gompertz functions have a sigmoidal shape and have many applications across different domains. For example in biology, Gompertz functions are used to model bacterial and tumour cell growth.

---

To see how your equations relate to the more general Gompertz functions, let's rewrite the equations for s

[image]

On a side note, we can see that taking the double-log of s (i.e. log log s) linearises the equation as a function of the index.

We can now compare this with the more general Gompertz function

[image]

Taking the natural logarithm gives

[image]

We then set `a=1` and take the natural logarithm again

[image]

So the equations you give are algebraically identical to the Gompertz functions with parameters

[image]

---

Let's plot the function for the three sets of parameters that you give in your post (I use R here but it's easy to do something similar in e.g. Python)

```r
# Define a function f which takes the index and two parameters a and b
# We use a helper function scale01 to scale the values of f in the interval [0,1]
# using min-max scaling
scale01 <- function(x) (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
f <- function(idx, a, b) scale01(a ^ (b ^ idx))

# Calculate s for the three different sets of parameters and 
# using integer index values from 0 to 100 
idx <- 0:100
lst <- lapply(list(
    s1 = list(a = 0.0000000001, b = 0.97),
    s2 = list(a = 0.0000000002, b = 0.962),
    s3 = list(a = 0.0000000003, b = 0.953)),
    function(pars) f(idx, a = pars$a, b = pars$b))

# Plot    
library(ggplot2)
df <- cbind(idx = idx, stack(lst))
ggplot(df, aes(idx, values, colour = ind)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Fascinating. Thanks for all the detail.